# (Java Number Pyramid) How do I get my numbers to have more spaces between them while lining up accurately when it is an integer is > 9?

Tags: java

I am having difficulty getting the desired output. I know there are problems that are similar to mine that is already posted, but I find it hard to relate my code to their solutions without a massive overhaul.

The solution for my class assignment:

[Supposed to continue until every direction of pyramid equals 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHvss.png)
My second method "spaces" is redundant and I am not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

> Blockq

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numPar();
        spaces();
    }

    private static void spaces() {
        int x = 0;
        if(x > 0 && x < 10) {
            System.out.print("   "); 
        } else if (x > 10 && x < 99) {
            System.out.print("  ");  
        } else if (x > 99) {
            System.out.print(" ");  
        }
    }

    private static void numPar() {
        int spaces = 14;
        for(int i = 0; i<= 7; i++) {
            for(int u = 0; u<spaces; u++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            spaces--;
            spaces--;
            for(int j = 0 ; j <i ; j++) {
                System.out.print(""+ (int) Math.pow(2,j)+" ");
            }
            for(int k = i ; k >=0 ; k--) {
                System.out.print(""+ (int) Math.pow(2,k)+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use built-in methods like `System.out.printf()`?

Comment: Printf is definitely allowed @markspace

Comment: @Carcigenicate Are you saying you saying that if number = 999 then the length should be 4 ? I am not sure what you are referring to when you say adding paddings.

Answer (score 0):

I made every number take 3 places using `String.format("%3s", (int) Math.pow(2, j))`. You can make it dynamic by replacing the number `3` here with the length of the largest number you'll print. I also changed the number of spaces in your print statements. Here is the full code that prints an evenly spaced pyramid:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    numPar();
    spaces();
}

private static void spaces() {
    int x = 0;
    if (x > 0 && x < 10) {
        System.out.print("   ");
    } else if (x > 10 && x < 99) {
        System.out.print("   ");
    } else if (x > 99) {
        System.out.print("   ");
    }
}

private static void numPar() {
    int spaces = 14;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        for (int u = 0; u < spaces; u++) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        spaces--;
        spaces--;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print("" + String.format("%3s", (int) Math.pow(2, j)) + " ");
        }
        for (int k = i; k >= 0; k--) {
            System.out.print("" + String.format("%3s", (int) Math.pow(2, k)) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

**`String.format` explanation**:-
`String.format("%3s", str)` will print the string `str`, padding it with spaces, to make the total length 3 if it's less than 3. Note that you can write anything instead of 3 - I used 3 because your biggest number was of length 3.

So "A" will be printed as "_ _ A" (2 spaces), and "Ab" will be printed as "_ Ab" (1 space).

I just replaced `str` with your `Math.pow(2, j)`.

Comment: Could I have an explanation of 'string.format'? I want to understand what is going on with what you added but I am not going to pretend

Comment: I'll explain but have a read through [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) first, you'll understand it.

Comment: I have been trying to understand for the past hour, but I feel like this method is way what I am learning right now

Comment: you are a gift; i appreciate your help!~