# Cannot print pyramid of numbers

Tags: java

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        int n = 4;

        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--)
        {
            System.out.print(k);
        }
        for (int l = 2; l <= i; l++)
        {
            System.out.print(l);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = 3; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int n = 3;

        for (int j = 0; j <= n - i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--)
        {
            System.out.print(k);
        }
        for (int l = 2; l <= i; l++)
        {
            System.out.print(l);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }


My output:

Enter height: 
12
1
212
32123
4321234
543212345
65432123456
7654321234567
876543212345678
98765432123456789
109876543212345678910
1110987654321234567891011
12111098765432123456789101112
```

It prints correctly, but with no spacing...
Would I need another for loop with a println that just prints a space under the first for loop?

Also, if I did that would it still work for double digit heights such as 12?

I would greatly appreciate help, thank you.

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147546/java-number-pyramid-how-do-i-get-my-numbers-to-have-more-spaces-between-them-w/

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It is supposed to countdown on one side, hit 1, then count up on the other side.

Comment: @Kartik I know there is a much simpler solution. I am not that advanced to know that. I also want to learn from my code. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It would be better if you post the screenshot of your desired output

Comment: @suvojit_007 https://gyazo.com/35e86f7987472439a5540cdb0bff7078 I reformed my code and that's what I get when I enter single digit numbers as my height. However, when I enter 12 I get: https://gyazo.com/12452f132614adddb4b5071110edc9bd

Comment: Your code looks fine. Your code takes one extra space each for two digit number and that's the reason you're getting such a result.

Comment: @suvojit_007 So there's nothing I can do to even it out on each side?

Comment: You can give a space after printing each number but the problem will be the same for three digit numbers.

Comment: @suvojit_007 When I do that I get: https://gyazo.com/6dfc60cda3c76c6072a934565e014306 I don't care about three digit numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to play around with spaces.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {

    int n = height;
    int n2 = height + 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
        System.out.print("" + String.format("%3s", " ") + " ");
    }
    for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--) {
        System.out.print("" + String.format("%3s", k) + " ");
    }
    for (int l = 2; l <= i; l++) {
        System.out.print("" + String.format("%3s", l) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}
```

**OUTPUT:** For height 10

```
                                      1 

                                  2   1   2 

                              3   2   1   2   3 

                          4   3   2   1   2   3   4 

                      5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5 

                  6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6 

              7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 

          8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 

      9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 

 10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```